# Derive formula for curl

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I want to derive the formula for curl in terms of basis vectors. I start with
$$\def\p{\partial} \nabla \times F =(e_x\p_x+e_y\p_y+e_z\p_z)\times(f_xe_x+f_ye_y+f_ze_z)\\=e_x\p_x\times (f_xe_x+f_ye_y+f_ze_z)+\text{Two similar terms} $$
but I do not understand how one evaluates $(e_x\p_x)\times (f_xe_x)$, what happens to $\p_x$? Can I just $(e_x\p_x)\times (f_xe_x)=\p_xf_x(e_x\times e_x)$?

This method worked with deriving the formula for $\nabla\cdot F$ because I just said $(e_x \p_x)\cdot(f_xe_x)=\p_x[ e_x\cdot f_xe_x]=\p_xf_x$ but I don't think this is technically right, it only worked because $\p_x=1$

Comment: "Can I just $(e_x\p_x)\times (f_xe_x)=\p_xf_x(e_x\times e_x)$?"
Yes, in this case that works. Had $e_x$ not been constant then you would have to take a derivative also of $e_x$ using the product rule.

Comment: @md2perpe So say I had some general $e_u$ then it would be $(e_u \partial_u) \times (f_u e_u)=(e_u)\times (\partial_u [f_u e_u])= (e_u)\times (\frac{\partial f_u}{\partial u} e_u+\frac{\partial e_u}{\partial u} f_u)$?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @md2perpe if you copy paste this into an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I just $(e_x\partial_x)\times(f_x e_x)=\partial_x f_x(e_x\times e_x)$

Yes, in this case that works. Had $e_x$ not been constant then you would have to take a derivative also of $e_x$ using the product rule:

$$
(e_u \partial_u) \times (f_u e_u)=(e_u)\times (\partial_u [f_u e_u])= (e_u)\times (\frac{\partial f_u}{\partial u} e_u+\frac{\partial e_u}{\partial u} f_u).
$$